# Azure media service asset management

Tags: c#, azure, azure-media-services

After reading all official documentation on [azure media services using .net sdk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh973613.aspx)

I'm unable to manage assets under scenario say in a music streaming application.

Problems:-

1. When new Asset with single AssetFile is created then new task can encode it to Smooth Streaming but there is no way to add new media files in that asset later and encode only newly added files(correct me if i am wrong)
2. Even if new asset is created each time new AssetFile need to be added then it will limit the number of files one can have.(As max number of assets are limited to (Number of Encoding Reserved Units + Number of On-Demand Streaming Reserved Units + 1) * 10,000)

So how am I supposed to manage assets, if i want to make scalable music streaming application design?

Answer (score 2):

Since No one answered it here, Anyone looking for same kind of suggestion can head over to the answer at [msdn forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/e05b671c-c07c-403c-b33f-c3d4690bb075/asset-management?forum=MediaServices#50033d00-43b8-4e09-9433-caaca4694158)

Comment: You can add a little explanation here too.